# Calculate sum of one column - jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, sum

I'd like to calculate a sum of values in specific column in a table.

the table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Old cost</td>

            <td class="oldCost">9 990,-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="discount">
            <td>Service - 2</td>

            <td>2 000,-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="template">
            <td>Theme - 3</td>

            <td>0,-</td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="result">

            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is the values are like this (X XXX,-) so I need to **trim** (or explode?) it to a normal number and **then create a sum of all the numbers** and display it in `<tr class="result>`

I tried many ways but the only thing I got is NaN displaying instead of a sum. It **doesn't include** the trim function because I just didn't find the right function for it.

```
$("table").change(function(){
        var theTotal = 0;
        $("td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {

            theTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
            $(".result").text(theTotal);
        });
    });
```

Comment: what does the number mean? `9 990` means `9990`?

Comment: `$(this).val()` should be `$(this).text().split(',')[0].replace(/ /g,'')` . Also the `$(".result")` should be placed outside the `.each`

Comment: @KingKing Yes, it is how we write prices in our language. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `parseInt` in your code, I am assuming that you expect all prices to be integer values, and always end with the string ",-". If my assumption is true, the following code should work:

```
$("table").change(function(){
    var theTotal = 0;
    $("td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
        var val = $(this).text().replace(" ", "").replace(",-", "");
        theTotal += parseInt(val);
    });
    $(".result").html('<td colspan="2">' + theTotal + ',- </td>');
});
```

The code removes the spaces from the integer part, and removes as well the "empty decimals" token. See [the replace function reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace).

If my assumption is wrong, meaning that the prices can be float value, you can remove the dashes and replace the comma with a dot, then use `parseFloat`.

Comment: Please note that this creates illegal html - a text node surrounded by "tr" tags with no "td"s. The last row should have tds in and the adding function should include a check if you're not in the last tr with each adding-up. There is also no native jQuery function that will check HTML change, and the function "change" will normally only detect input value change. See here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386058/html-table-onchange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386058/html-table-onchange).

Comment: @nzn That is a good point, I edited my answer. I used a 2-column td, so it does not match the nth-child accessor. I agree with the change event, and also noticed it, but I guess the OP triggers it manually somewhere in their code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using "val" for the contents of "td"'s, nor will "change" work on the table.
You have to create a function and have it trigger in whatever javascript changes the values in the tds, like so (this will remove all characters that are not numerals or the decimal point):

```
tablechange = function(){
    var theTotal = 0;
    $("tr:not(:last-child) td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
        theTotal += parseFloat($(this).html().replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''));
    });
    $(".result").text(theTotal);
};
tablechange();
```

Comment: Don't you know how to insert a specific string after the result, please? `$('.result').text(theTotal).after(',-');` is not working for me.

Comment: you could just use the '+' operator for appending strings so you would do $(".result").text(theTotal+',-');

Comment: Also as I've pointed out in a previous comment above, you should have td's in the last row to make it legal HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You want `$(this).html`, not `$(this).val` to get the text inside each table cell. Then trim everything after the comma with `substr`and collapse the spaces with `replace` and you can add the numbers together:

```
var value;
var theTotal = 0;
$("td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
    value = $(this).html();
    value = value.substr(0, value.indexOf(','));
    value = value.replace(' ', '');
    theTotal += parseInt(value);
    $(".result").text('Total: ' + theTotal);
});
```

Here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDhL5/)**